# Open A File From Dialog Box

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to validate the active workbook is the proper workbook from the proper folder in our shared drive. Otherwise, the user will save data and it will not be shared. A safety measure to ensure data entry.

Some users save a copy of the aforementioned 'active workbook' to their PC off of the shared drive, which leads to data loss.

I want to use a message box to alert the user they will not save data in the group file, then ask if they would like to open that file.
Upon hitting "Yes", the other file would open while leaving the existing document open.
The selection "No" or "Cancel" would end sub.

GOAL:

- Use a message box to alert the user that they are not working on the shared document.
  Upon selection, the yes button open the correct document.

CODE (in Workbook):

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
    Set Sheet1 = Sheets("Invoices")
    Dim folpath As String
    Dim mypath As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    folpath = "K:\Purchasing_Utilities\1_UTILITIES\4_VENDOR_INVOICES\GHOST_CARD\Active_Pay_Tracker_22.xlsm"
    mypath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    
    If mypath = folpath Then
        GoTo Skip
    Else
        MsgBox "This file source is a locally saved file. To share changes, please open the Tracker in the K: drive." _
          & " Would you like the system to open this file now?", VbMsgBoxStyle = vbOKCancel + vbCritical
            
        'Here is where I am trying to get the message box to open the document

Skip
    Sheet1.Range("P:P").Sort Key1:=Sheet1.Range("P:P"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Activate
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an example:

```
Result = MsgBox("This file source is a locally saved file. To share changes, please open the Tracker in the K: drive. Would you like the system to open this file now?", vbOKCancel + vbCritical)
If Result = vbOKCancel Then
MsgBox "You clicked OK"
Else: MsgBox "You clicked Critical"
End If
```

This looks as follows:

[image]

If you press "Ok", this is what you see:

[image]

So, if you want a `vbYes`, you'll need to add this to the original messagebox (which currently does not have a "Yes" button) and add the corresponding `Result` handling (`if Result = vbYes then ... (open file)`).

Comment: Thank you Dominique! Do you know if it is possible to open a file as an action from vbYes selection?

Comment: @Beej: I adapted my answer accordingly.